# How to play Terraria without Steam?

Tags: steam, terraria

I'm trying to play Terraria without initializing Steam but it is not working it displays

*Please launch the game from your Steam client*

Is there a possible way to do it?.

Comment: Terraria is now available on the XBox 360 ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to play Terraria without using Steam. Is downloading Terraria Wrapper and executing it. This tool is often used to play Terraria in other resolution but also helps to initialize the game without the need of the Steam platform.

Comment: There's also a wrapper that allows for Terraria to be played on a Mac. If you own the game through Steam, you can run the wrapper once and play it without Steam. Just in case anyone was curious.

Answer (score 7):

I don't believe there is. Terraria is solely run from Steam, and the only possible way you could run it outside of Steam was if it was Pirated (which is illegal.) You can still play it if you're not connected to the internet, however. You simply run Steam in offline mode.

Comment: offline mode not working :/

Comment: @Washu See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19234/is-there-any-way-to-start-steam-in-offline-mode-without-logging-in-first

Comment: It's 2022 and now [Terraria is available on GOG](https://www.gog.com/en/game/terraria). Usually GOG games can run without GOG client.