# Transferring games

Tags: steam, pc

I have built a PC back a couple of years ago which requires a wired Ethernet cable (didn’t come with a wireless NIC). I have purchased a game through Steam when I was with my dad in Florida and I have been wanting to play it for a couple of months now. As of right now, I currently do not have the resources to purchase a wireless NIC, as I am in the process of moving. I do have a laptop which has Steam but due to it’s specs, cannot run the game I want to run. I was wondering if it was possible to copy the game launcher and all of the required files (including .dlls) onto my gaming PC and run it from there. I don’t know if it can due to Steam’s functionalities but I thought it was worth asking.

Comment: Related: [How do I move Steam games to a new computer without re-downloading them?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12695/how-do-i-move-steam-games-to-a-new-computer-without-re-downloading-them)

Comment: I originally voted this as duplicate, but on second thought I think this question is a bit more specialized than the other, since it's about transferring games *without access to the internet*, rather than "without downloading the games". In other words: even if you can transfer the *game files* without internet, Steam will probably still want to access the internet to verify ownership. Answers to this question will have to address that.

Comment: Just sign in too your account on the gaming pc. Also format better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get steam to recognize game files downloaded on another machine?](/q/214120/4797) | Running Steam without Internet access: [How to make Steam allow automatic login even when not connected to the internet?](/q/298284/4797) | [How can you install Steam games offline?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/4293/4797) | [Is there any way to start Steam in offline mode without logging in first?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/19234/4797) | [How can I use Steam without connecting to Steam's servers?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/237552/4797)