# Start Steam in Offline Mode Without an Internet Connection

Tags: steam

I need to start Steam in offline mode without first logging in and without having an Internet connection. I know there are already questions like this, but there are no decent answers that I can comprehend. Is there just a simple way to do it?

It's not a duplicate of the other question because that's not my problem. Read both questions fluently. He has possible connection to the Internet, I don't. Also, his question is 4 years out of date.

Comment: Please explain what you don't understand about those answers so we can help.

Comment: Most of the answers involved like 30 lines of code or something (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19234/is-there-any-way-to-start-steam-in-offline-mode-without-logging-in-first?rq=1) and for some reason the .bat file option isn't working.

Comment: Unfortunetly, "but i did not understand the answers" does not override the fact that this is a duplicate of the question. If you build your reputation up a little, you can post a bounty on the question, requesting a simplified response to the problem.

Comment: That question hasn't been answered at all, seeing as none of the options provided in any of the answers work (for me, at least).

Comment: Just because it doesnt work for you,does not mean is has not been answered. We promote answering a question for the community,not the individual. I would suggest downvoting any answer that does not work. Furthermore, we don't use "out of date" as a valid reason to create a new question, either. This is something currently being discussed on meta.

Comment: Well Steam gets updated pretty much every other day so of course it's not going to work. Maybe on StackExchange's other sites you don't use "out of date" as a valid reason to create a new question, but I don't see why you wouldn't when the only answer that once works literally does not work anymore. If you don't know the answer, don't post on this question at all. Also, 30 or so years ago, people were taught the Earth had 5 continents. That's now been shown to be incorrect today, but if I asked that question on a StackExchange site, would you use the "out of date" excuse to not answer again?

Comment: Also, I'd like to add that since the other question was 3-4 years old, the correct answer was not found there and was found here. This is not a duplicate of that one because obviously Ross Ridge knew I was asking a (albeit slightly) different question, otherwise his answer would be similar to one on the other question.

Comment: That's the whole point of the duplicate system; so that others with the same problem can find existing answers. The fact that none of the answers worked for you, or you think the answers are out of date, is immaterial. The question has already been asked; that's what matters. We amalgamate all the possible solutions under a single question.  Your question will probably go out of date just as quickly as the original. If we allowed duicatez because answers are out of date, we'd soon have dozens of questions, all asking the same thing, and all of them for different versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot start Steam without logging in. You need to either log in with a username and password or with saved credentials. You cannot login to Steam with a username and password without an Internet connection. You cannot save credentials without first logging into Steam with a user name and password. You cannot start Steam in offline mode without saved credentials.

What this all means is that in order to start Steam in offline mode, you need to have previously connected your PC to the Internet and successfully logged in to Steam. The "Don't save account credentials on this computer" setting must have been turned off when you did so. If you haven't already done this then there's nothing you can do to start Steam without an Internet connection.

If you are ever able to connect your PC to the Internet then you should follow [Valve's instructions on how to use offline mode](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3160-agcb-2555):

> #### Using Offline Mode on a PC.
>
> Please follow the instructions below to configure Offline Mode on your PC:
>
> 1. Start Steam online - make sure the **Remember my password** box on the login window is checked
> 2. Verify that all game files are completely updated - you can see the update status for a game under the **Library** section (when the game shows as **100% - Ready** it is ready to be played in Offline Mode)
> 3. Launch the game you would like to play offline to verify that there are no further updates to download - shut down the game and return to Steam once you have confirmed that the game can be played
> 4. Go to **Steam > Settings** to ensure the **Don't save account credentials** on this computer option is **not* selected
> 5. From the main Steam window, go to the *Steam* menu and select *Go Offline*
> 6. Click **Restart in Offline Mode** to restart Steam in Offline Mode

All the other answers you may have seen are solutions for if you didn't perform steps 5 and 6. There's nothing you can do to avoid having to perform the other steps, as they're part of Steam's method of copy protection. Requiring that you log in at least once and validate that your account actually has purchased the games installed on your PC is how it tries to limit piracy.

Answer (score 1):

## The simplest method:

Yes: as mentioned in the [linked question you posted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19234/is-there-any-way-to-start-steam-in-offline-mode-without-logging-in-first?rq=1) you can simply **disable your internet connection / unplug whatever connects you to the internet**. This is by far the *simplest* method of getting Steam to start in offline mode.

## Steam -offline parameter (no longer works)

A commenter suggests on the same question, and there's also a [forum post on the same nature](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3083915) that you can pass the `-offline` parameter:

```
Steam.exe -offline
```

However, this doesn't appear to be a [documented command line parameter for Steam](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options).

Comment: Please dont simply repost from another question. If you are taking the answer from the other question, by definition you are identifying the other question as a duplicate. Posting an answer just makes it harder for mods to clean up

Comment: Downvoter you should note that the [linked question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19234/is-there-any-way-to-start-steam-in-offline-mode-without-logging-in-first?rq=1) explicitly states the OP does not wish to disable their internet; however, this question does not have the same requirements and therefore I feel it's valid.

Comment: Many don't. Many also don't appear to read both questions.