# Starting Steam in Offline Mode doesn't work

Tags: steam, networking

I'm currently at a university with a firewall that blocks certain connections, and Steam appears to be in that list. When Steam starts, it gives a connection error, along with the option to start in Offline Mode. Choosing to start in Offline Mode, however, yields the same result, with Steam still attempting to communicate with the servers (and subsequently failing). I'm using version 3.53.1.42. Is there some way to completely force Steam to use offline mode before it runs?

Edit: Following the instructions on the second answer posted on [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19234/is-there-any-way-to-start-steam-in-offline-mode-without-logging-in-first) (my question was marked as a possible duplicate of the linked one) has only made things worse, as now Steam asks for my password when starting up. After inputting my password, it still gives a "failed to connect" error.

Comment: Try turning off wifi and then starting it in offline mode, then turning wifi back on.

Comment: I don't know what the latest version of steam is, but if that isn't the latest version, maybe try updating it?

Comment: @Sumurai8 Linked questions did not solve the issue. This question has been updated with the current status.

Comment: Did you log in from an unblocked machine?

Comment: No. Steam is currently only logged in on the laptop I'm writing this from and my phone; however, I haven't attempted a login on my phone in over a week.