# Is there any way to start Steam in offline mode with code after the new steam client?

Tags: steam

I am working on a project that logs you automatically in Steam. I want to add another login method that logs you in with offline mode. Before the new Steam client, I was editing the loginusers.vdf file and all was working good. But after the new Steam client, it doesn't work anymore.

Does anyone has any idea for how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to start Steam in offline mode without logging in first?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19234/is-there-any-way-to-start-steam-in-offline-mode-without-logging-in-first)

Comment: No its an old method it doesnt work on the new steam client. @galacticninja

Comment: There are two answers there. Do both answers not work?

Comment: Yes both of them doesnt work anymore. I am trying to solve this problem over 1 week and didnt find anything. @galacticninja

Comment: `loginusers.vdf` is not synchronized with the Steam Cloud, but they likely started storing and checking it's hash because this was a security hole. Since it doesn't even work for offline mode it must be stored locally (unless it's pinging the server, but obviously that's not offline mode then and would be bypassed by a simple firewall). It may be possible to find and circumvent this, but Valve's binary VDF format is hell to parse and there's hundreds of files where they could hide it, so it'd be **a lot of work** *if it even exists*.

Comment: @l3l_aze So you saying that its impossible to do this after the new steam client ?

Comment: @Ali Not necessarily impossible, but extremely unlikely that someone will figure it out unless they put in *a lot* of work or have some amazing luck. And even if it is possible it may make Valve mad and could lead to a ban as it would be circumventing security. All theoretical of course, as they've been very lax about third-party tools and people playing with both their encoded (not encrypted) and plaintext config files for years, but that stuff wasn't security holes.

Comment: @l3l_aze I just want to make a software that logs users in steam with offline mode, so i dont want to harm the steam servers or etc. Hope someone finds a solution for this. I will keep working on it too if i find something i will post it in here.