# Steam won't start in Offline Mode

Tags: steam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to start Steam in offline mode without logging in first?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19234/is-there-any-way-to-start-steam-in-offline-mode-without-logging-in-first)

Yesterday I was at an airport and had no wifi, I wanted to play one of my steam games. Unfortunately, Steam games won't run without Steam running first, some don't even have `.exe`'s.

So I start up Steam I choose 'Offline Mode' , but it pops up an error message saying that it couldn't connect to the Steam Network.

What's going on?

What exactly is 'Offline Mode' for if it won't start Steam without internet?

(I am sure that my Steam client was fully updated)

Comment: or you might take a look at [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2360/reliability-of-steams-off-line-mode) as well.

Comment: for offline mode to work as intended, you have to have switched to it once before while being online. I don't know if [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/19235/88) works without that. At the very least your user credentials must be in the Steam folder, so if you chose to not let Steam remember your password it most certainly will not work

Comment: I would like to especially point out that [Gnoupi's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/2363/3917) is what you are most interested.  Even if you do everything correctly, sometimes steam still thinks there's an update and requires a network connection.  Its really annoying as I often travel and run into this issue quite often.