# Can you get acheivements in Offline Mode?

Tags: steam

In offline mode, I can't even look at my acheivements. But say I make a lot of progress in a game in offline mode anyway. Do I still obtain them?

Comment: It would depend on the game; do you have a specific one in mind?

Comment: The answer is **Yes! But you have to run it in online mode at least once first..** *And they don't register onto your Steam profile until you connect to the internet.* | You can find your answer at this question: [Why do some games allow offline Steam achievements?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46307/why-do-some-games-allow-offline-steam-achievements)