# Can you play offline and earn Steam achievements for Hogwarts Legacy?

Tags: steam, achievements, hogwarts-legacy

Do I need an internet connection in order to play Hogwarts Legacy or can I simply play it offline without internet? And will I still earn my Steam achievements if I play offline?

There is this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1609/can-i-earn-steam-achievements-while-offline) regarding earning Steam achievements while playing offline and the [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/165285/165402) is basically that it depends on the game. So what is it for Hogwarts Legacy?